# Ubuntu Lucid and nginx with vsftpd

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, nginx, ftp

After my initial freakout with getting tomcat sorted I have moved onto something a bit simpler and so far (from what little I know of sysadmin'ing) I've managed to get vsftpd and nginx installed and working.

I have setup a subdomain (as a test) for sandbox.ourcompany.com and I had it correctly being picked up and served by nginx as a virtual host.

My goal was to create a user account for user "ourcompany", let them login and upload files to /var/www/vhosts/ourcompany.com/sandbox/public. I thought I'd try it with my account (davidsf) first.

But I fear I have messed up the permissions.

Just to recap, I'm on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS, nginx and vsftpd from the repository. I am logging in as my account that is also apart of (I think this is right) the www-data group.

I uploaded a text file to the above path, but I get forbidden by nginx.

```
drwxr-xr-x 4 root     root     4.0K 2010-07-09 21:35 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root     root     4.0K 2010-07-09 21:35 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 root     root     4.0K 2010-07-09 21:35 logs
drwxrwx--x 2 www-data www-data 4.0K 2010-07-09 21:39 public
```

This is my permissions:

```
www-data:x:33:davidsf
admin:x:106:davidsf
davidsf:x:1000:
```

How do I make it so if I create a site, I add a non-shell user that they can access the FTP server and manage their files easily? I'm not able to install any control panels unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is yours answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/253069/vsftpd-only-ftp-access-for-local-user/253090#253090) . You should user virtual suers. Look at the link and some fields with #carefull . you should change them. You can use mysql-pam and other user. change root to $cirtualuser name and so on.