# How to allow user1 to 1 directory and another user2 to another directory. Not only home directory

Tags: centos, ftp

In CentOS, how can i specify user1 to directory /var/www/html and user2 to directory /home/user2, and as default user3 and all others to there home directory?

My config file has following /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf:

```
# You may specify an explicit list of local users to chroot() to their home
# directory. If chroot_local_user is YES, then this list becomes a list of
# users to NOT chroot().
#chroot_list_enable=YES
chroot_local_user=YES
# (default follows)
#chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd/chroot_list
```

- This allow all users to there home directory only, but i need to specify user1 to another directory for full web directory access, and user2 only to his home directory (for personal ftp upload/download)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use **virtualuser**  setup; Look [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/253069/vsftpd-only-ftp-access-for-local-user/253090#253090)
there is mine example of what to do. look at **local_root=/var/ftpserver/**  or at pam.d and change it for mysql. there you should be able to costumize directory and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You may get access to WEB folder inside user's standard location - by mounting local folders using

`mount --bind`

It then works with vsftpd chrooted accounts. Don't forget to add entries into **fstab**