# Using an allowed user list with VSFTPD

Tags: linux, ftp, vsftpd

According to the Wiki [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Very_Secure_FTP_Daemon#Limiting_user_login), you can only allow certain users to log in over FTP using the following configuration in your `/etc/vsftp.conf` file:

```
userlist_enable=YES
userlist_file=/etc/vsftp.user_list
userlist_deny=NO
```

I've configured my system to use this configuration, and I only have one user which I'd like to expose over FTP named `streams`, so my `/etc/vsftp.user_list` looks like this:

```
streams
```

Interestingly enough, I cannot log in once I enable to user list. If I change `userlist_enable` to `NO`, then things work properly, but if I enable it, I can't log in all, it just keeps trying to reconnect. I don't get a login failed message, it just keeps trying to reconnect when using `lftp`.

My `/etc/vsftp.conf` file is available on Pastebin [here](http://pastebin.com/zn7GuvvS) and my `/etc/vsftp.user_list` is available [here](http://pastebin.com/kezU4Rsh).

What am  I doing wrong here? I'd just like to only make the `streams` user able to log in.

Comment: And your logs say...?

Comment: No important errors, only "FAIL LOGIN: Client '127.0.0.1'"

Comment: xferlog_file is commented in your config file. What happens when you login from command line?

Comment: I uncommented it, no change. I'm only logging in from the commandline, I'm using `lftp`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A cursory glance doesn't show anything wrong with your config file... the problem may lie elsewhere.

You've probably already tried this but it might be worth checking the following:

- Make sure that that whatever user vsftpd is running as has the appropriate privileges on `/etc/vsftp.user_list`. You don't have your own non-privileged user configured with the `nopriv_user` directive, but the default is nobody.
- Try commenting out the `chroot_local_users` directive to see if there is an issue with chroot-ing.
- Have you restarted the vsftpd process after making changes? A common [Doh!](http://youtu.be/khSIYmTzt6U) sysadmin moment for me is I make the config changes but forget to HUP to the process... (embarrassing, yes I know).
- Try running vsftpd directly from the command line so any errors go to STDERR.
- Have you configured your user `streams` to have `/bin/false` as a login shell? Try using `/bin/nologin` instead. `/bin/false` will prevent that user from logging in at all.
- As a last resort consider using [PAM and virtual users](https://serverfault.com/questions/253069/vsftpd-only-ftp-access-for-local-user).

Answer (score 1):

I may be late, but i figured this out. I ran into this issue while configuring mine. Uncomment the following line in the config file:

`#local_enable=YES *Change To* local_enable=YES`